# How do I create a partition in Ubuntu 16.04 after installation?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, lvm

[image]

I did not install lvm for my system. The main partition is the os partition and I want to create two sub partitions of 150 GB and 80 GB.

Also I am unable to unmount the `/dev/sda/` in gparted in live usb to create a new partition table.

So how do I create the partition without formatting again?

Comment: i want to create the partition of /dev/sda2/

Comment: You cannot modify mounted partitions. Little lock icons show mounted. Use live installer, you may also have to unmount / swapoff the swap partition. You are not showing LVM, but if LVM, you need to use LVM tools.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a live Ubuntu USB/CD and partition off some of your main HDD through Disk Utility.

As mentioned in the comments, you may not be able to partition the live volume while it's mounted.